# Rails - Expiring Cached Actions from Resque (a Delayed Job alternative)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, resque

I have Resque queue that processes a particular model to do some post processing. Once this model is updated I would like to expire the cached view action.

I have a Sweeper setup and working, but it only observes changes made to the models in Controller Actions.

I know it is not very MVC to be expiring cached items from my model, but all my post processing logic is contained in my models.

Ideally I would like to not double up on my cache busting code, so if I could get my existing sweeper to watch model changes that would be ideal.

Alternatively I would settle for expriing the action cache from inside my model OR a model observer.

p.s.: I can expire cached fragments from within a model observer I have setup, but not actions.

I'd really like to know what the best practice is here. I'm sure I am not the only one who has this requirment.

Thanks.

I'm wondering if something like this is the way to go:

http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2011/07/rails-wykorzystywanie-sweeperow-poza-kontrolerami-na-samych-modelach/

Answer (score 1):

Since I wasn't able to add my comment on that site you linked to.  I'll put it here:

In Rails 3.1.3, if you instantiate the controller and then try calling expire_fragment, you'll get errors about trying to call host on NilClass.

After some experimenting, I remembered that functional tests can instantiate your controller.  So I changed the instantiation code to:

```
@controller ||= ApplicationController.new

if @controller.request.nil?
      @controller.request = ActionDispatch::TestRequest.new
end
```

This seems to work, even in production, even using rails console.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I came up with the following solution:

Added my existing sweeper to the list of object observers in application.rb:

```
config.active_record.observers = :app_sweeper
```

Added code to the sweeper methods to instantiate the @controller object if it was missing in the sweeper (which is what happens when coming via a object instead of a controller).

```
@controller ||= ActionController::Base.new
```

I could then use the expire_fragment method to expire the cached action, with the following tidbit.

```
expire_fragment("#{ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host]}/items/#{item.id}")
```

That said, mj1531's answer might prove to be a nicer solution if it means that I can use the expire_action method instead of faking it with the expire fragment. I will report back when I have test it out and select the best answer.